# Is this expression "Is there some connection between X and Y" clear and idiomatic?

Tags: meaning

I asked a question at [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3362347/697527) SE

> Is there some connection between these 2 empirical cumulative distribution functions?

This description can be viewed as

"Is there some connection between these 2 math objects?"

or

"Is there some connection between these 2 math formula?"

## question

Is this expression "Is there some connection between X and Y" clear and idiomatic?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to this question is yes.

It is correct idiomatic English to say

> "Is there some connection between X and Y?"

and any native English speaker should know exactly what you mean.

> "Are X and Y connected?"

is another way of asking the same question.

Comment: As Peter Jennings says. 
Alternatively you might use *a* or *any* instead of 'some'. Or ask, 'Can you find any connection between X and Y?'